# SQL Server driver updates for Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010, driver

Dates aren't displaying since upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012. I want / need to somehow update the driver being used.

The database originally was developed using SQL Server 2000, so that is, for the most part, the driver version being used. This is causing the dates not to display without me changing the code on front end to `Now()`. The column type is `datetime`.

Ran a script to check the driver versions and this is what I got:

```
session_id     protocol_type    driver_version
---------------------------------------------
  51                TSQL        Unknown driver
  52                TSQL        SQL Server 2008
  53                TSQL        Unknown driver
  54                TSQL        Unknown driver
  55                TSQL        Unknown driver
  57                TSQL        Unknown driver
  59                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
  61                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
  62                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
  63                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
  64                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
  66                TSQL        SQL Server 2000
```

So how do I update these drivers?

I need to have the correct date displayed based on the column datatype `datetime`.